# Validate Custom Input URL fields with jQuery & Regex

Tags: jquery, regex, input, jquery-validate, validation

So basically I'm trying to validate URLs (http://www.x) - currently working - and on top of that, validate jsFiddle (input must start with "http://www.jsfiddle.net/") & stackoverflow URLs (input must start with "http://www.stackoverflow.com/")

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eAnS9/

The validation is the [bassistance validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), which is [documented here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods).

Any idea how to validate the fields correctly based on their beginning values?

**UPDATE:** It must work with/integrate with bassistance current validation, maybe as a custom url function in bassistance source code? (there is where the url regex is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `validator.addMethod()` to create a custom rule.  This one should do the trick:

```
//--- Add a domain-check rule
jQuery.validator.addMethod ("domainChk", function (value, element, params) {

        if (this.optional (element) )
            return true;

        //--- Get the target domain, this will be in the rel attribute.
        var targDomain  = $(element).attr ("rel");
        var regExp      = new RegExp ("^https?:\/\/(www.)?" + targDomain + "\/", "i");

        return regExp.test (value);
    },
    function errmess (params, element) {
        return "This must be a valid URL for " + $(element).attr ("rel");
    }
);
```

Now connect it to a CSS class. :

```js
jQuery.validator.addClassRules ( { domainChk: {domainChk: true} } );
```

The `domainChk` rule expects the required domain to be in the ***rel*** attribute of the input, like so:

```html
<input class="field required url domainChk" rel="jsfiddle.com"      ...>
<input class="field required url domainChk" rel="stackoverflow.com" ...>
```

That's it!   [**See it all in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pD5Pp/3/)

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks very much Brock, I learned a lot today:)

Answer (score 0):

could be better but

```
   var Reg = /https?:\/\/(w{3}\.)?(jsfiddle|stackoverflow)(.com\/)/
```

is what i used.
http://jsfiddle.net/eAnS9/